# How to create Ref Cursor type which can be stored in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, types, ref-cursor

I want to create a ref cursor type in database, so that I can declare variables of this type in sql developer command window using following statement :

```
variable PO_Ref_Csr_Out RefCursorTyp;
```

In the declaration RefCursorTyp is the stored ref cursor type in database

I want to use this PO_Ref_Csr_Out variable in Anonymous pl/sql block to test some procedures.

How to create this RefCursorTyp in database?

I am not aware about how to create type in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to make a strongly-typed cursor then create a package and define the type in that:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME
AS
  TYPE RefCursorTyp IS REF CURSOR
    RETURN SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;

  PROCEDURE get_Strongly_Typed_Cursor (
    out_cursor OUT RefCursorTyp
  );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME
AS
  PROCEDURE get_Strongly_Typed_Cursor (
    out_cursor OUT RefCursorTyp
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN out_cursor FOR
     SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then when you want to use it in PL/SQL you can:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME.RefCursorTyp;
BEGIN
  SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME.get_Strongly_Typed_Cursor(v_cur);
  -- Do something with the cursor.
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yFuSMpuK)

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is the simplest way to do what you described.

This is Oracle's command-line tool, **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    open :rc for
  3      select * from dept;
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, using Oracle's (free) **SQL Developer** GUI tool (code is similar to previous, but it won't work with anonyomus PL/SQL block but uses stored procedure that returns refcursor):

[image]

Comment: When I give "var rc refcursor" statement in PL/SQL Developer command window it return error "REFCURSOR not supported", why is this so?

Comment: I guess because **PL/SQL Developer** doesn't support that. I can't test it myself, I don't use that tool.

Comment: which oracle tool you use to run sql or pl/sql statements, I will try on that.

Comment: Code I originally posted was executed in SQL*Plus, command line tool. I added option which uses SQL Developer GUI tool; see if it helps.

Comment: Ok, it worked in Sql*Plus, it won't work in pl/sql developer. Thank you very much for your replies.